# Manual Mass Cropping Image

Tags: images

I have a bunch of images that I want to use for an AI dataset, however they all need to be 512x512. I can use a program to auto crop however it will quite often crop out the parts that are important. I want a program that will let me scale the image and drag a box that has specified dimensions (like 512x512) that will crop everything outside of the box.

I use Windows and the files are all PNGs

Comment: Check the list of [Fred's imagemagick scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php), perhaps there's one is among those that fits your needs (e.g., `xtract`?).